# Using Compressed Data Files (.cdf) from a Geodatabase in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, file-geodatabase, esri-geodatabase, osgeo4w

I am using **QGIS3** for a **file geodatabase** that was created on ArcMap. I can only access a few of the layers in the QGIS browser because most of them are stored using a **compressed data file (.cdf)**. When I tried executing **`ogr2ogr`** in the **OSGeo4W Shell**, I got the warning message "`(layer name) has a C:\Users\user\Desktop\geodatabase.gdb\compressedfilename.gdbtable.cdf file whose format is unhandled` for each layer that was stored with these .cdf files.

How can I decompress/convert these .cdf files to a usable format for QGIS without access to ArcMap? Is there a solution using R?

Comment: You would need a QGIS version that is using a GDAL version that supports this driver https://www.gdal.org/drv_filegdb.html with  ESRI SDK 1.4 or later.

Comment: @user30184 is that something I have to download separately? Or should I be looking for a different GDAL version all together?

Comment: GDAL version (like 2.4) does not matter, but GDAL must have been compiled from the source code somehow like in this document https://gist.github.com/zhm/2005158. The ESRI SDK seems to be here nowadays   https://github.com/Esri/file-geodatabase-api. Try to find such a build or someone who can make a build for you.